# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter<number>'

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I get this error when I try and assign `value` to be an EventEmitter of type number. Here is my code:

```
export class SpeedLimitComponent {
  @Output() public value = new EventEmitter<number>();

onInput(event: Event) {

this.value = +(\<HTMLInputElement\>event.target).value.split(',').join('');
console.log(this.value);
}
```

Error is above at `this.value` and below at `value`

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="..."
    class="form-control"
    style="text-align: right"
    [value]="value | number: '.0':'en-US'"
    (input)="onInput($event)"
  />
```

I've tried

```
...value: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

thinking that the instance I created needs to be the same as the EventEmitter. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `EventEmitter` incorrectly.

I don't know what is the use case, but you probably want to do this:

```
const num = +event.target.value; this.value.emit(num);
```

Event emitter is supposed to emit the value and not to assign value to it, and good practice is also to assign it to be `readonly`.

Note that the + in code snippet is needed for casting from `string` to `number`.